# I need to sort a CSV file using R, to be specific I need to convert some rows into columns

Tags: r

I have data in a CSV file that looks like the table below:

| SNP_Name | Sample_ID | Alle1-Forward | Allele2-Backward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rs12345 | JJ37 | T | T |
| rs12345 | JJ47 | C | C |
| rs67890 | JJ12 | A | A |
| rs67890 | JJ37 | A | G |

But I need something like this:

| Sample_ID | rs12345 | rs67890 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JJ37 | T,T | A,G |
| JJ47 | C,C | N/A |
| JJ12 | N/A | A,A |

How can I do that using R?

Answer (score 0):

First concatenate the strings in the last two columns with a comma in between, then reshape the data wider:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~SNP_Name, ~Sample_ID, ~`Alle1-Forward`, ~`Allele2-Backward`,
  "rs12345",     "JJ37",              "T",                 "T",
  "rs12345",     "JJ47",              "C",                 "C",
  "rs67890",     "JJ12",              "A",                 "A",
  "rs67890",     "JJ37",              "A",                 "G"
  )

df |> 
  unite(allele, 3:4, sep = ",") |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = SNP_Name, values_from = allele)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Sample_ID rs12345 rs67890
#>   <chr>     <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 JJ37      T,T     A,G    
#> 2 JJ47      C,C     <NA>   
#> 3 JJ12      <NA>    A,A
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If the data is large, you can try the package data.table (or try to increase the amount of data you can read into memory):

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~SNP_Name, ~Sample_ID, ~`Alle1-Forward`, ~`Allele2-Backward`,
  "rs12345",     "JJ37",              "T",                 "T",
  "rs12345",     "JJ47",              "C",                 "C",
  "rs67890",     "JJ12",              "A",                 "A",
  "rs67890",     "JJ37",              "A",                 "G"
)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

dcast(dt[, `:=`(allele = paste(`Alle1-Forward`, `Allele2-Backward`,
                               sep = ","))][, `:=`(c("Alle1-Forward", "Allele2-Backward"), NULL)], formula = Sample_ID ~ SNP_Name, value.var = "allele")
#>    Sample_ID rs12345 rs67890
#> 1:      JJ12    <NA>     A,A
#> 2:      JJ37     T,T     A,G
#> 3:      JJ47     C,C    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: My data is huge, i cannot concatinate the way you did

Comment: You can try data.table, see edit